# gsutil error /bootstrapping/gsutil.py

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

gsutil is giving me the following error. It is installed in its latest version on a linux suse 12. Can you help me?

gsutil

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py", line 13, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 46, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager

  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 36, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/yaml.py", line 31, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml_location_value
  File "/root/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/yaml_location_value.py", line 39, in <module>
    from ruamel import yaml
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple, Optional, Union, BinaryIO, IO, Any  # NOQA
ImportError: No module named typing
```

gcloud version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 272.0.0
bq 2.0.50
core 2019.11.16
gsutil 4.46
```

Python version:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Answer (score 1):

To install typing, execute `pip install typing`. Otherwise, you can check the [Install gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) documentation where there are also multiple other installation options.